# Bash filename expansion: Avoiding certain character

Tags: bash, filenames

In Bash, I can specify filenames `Foo1.png` through `Foo9.png` using `Foo[0-9].png`.  I can avoid `Foo5.png` using `Foo[1-46-9].png`.  Is there any way to specify a series of exclusions for the decimal digit?

For example, if I wanted to exclude `Foo3.png` and `Foo7.png`, I could use `Foo[0-24-689]`, but I would find a pattern like `Foo[^37].png` to be much easier to read.  That's Vim syntax, and Bash doesn't interpret it excluding `3` and `7`.  But I was wondering if Bash does have a pattern for character exclusion in its filename expansion.

If there is a solution that matches *all* single characters other than `3` or `7`, that would be helpful too, in some circumstances (such as the particular one that motivated this question, nowithstanding the overly simplified description above).

Comment: `Foo[^37].png` *should* work (at least in reasonably current versions of bash) although for POSIX compliance it would be `Foo[!37].png`

Comment: steeldriver: That only works to a point, you’d still see `Food.png`, which I don’t think was the expectation. To the OP, how do you suppose that bash is going to infer your intention to match all numerics (and only numerics) except those specified, without being told?

Comment: @steeldriver: That works for me.  Would you post it as the answer, including bxm's caveat?  As if often the case, *after* someone points out the "how", I am able to find it in [the documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html).

Comment: @bxm: As it turns out, steeldriver's solution works for my particular situation, even though it doesn't fully answer the question as described.  The question is oversimplified.  I added a paragraph indicating this.

Comment: What I meant to say was that `Foo[!37].png` worked for me, but not `Foo[^37].png`.  Based on *they's* answer below, however, I retried based on a new set of test files.  Both formats work, so something else must have been not right in the attempts that motivated this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `bash` shell understands both the regular expression-like `Foo[^37].png` pattern and the standard shell pattern `Foo[!37].png`, so you would be able to use them without problem unless you have other files with names like `Food.png` or `Fool.png` etc. that you need to exclude.

If `Foo[^37].png` does not work as expected in your script, then this indicates that you are not using `bash`, but some other shell such as, e.g. `dash` (possibly on a non-GNU system?)  Did you run the script with `sh` on the command line?  If so, don't, and use a proper `#!`-line in the script pointing to the correct shell interpreter.

Assuming there are names like `Food.png` that you want to exclude, to make sure that you get `Foo` followed by a digit, then `.png`, then use `Foo[0-9].png`.  To then exclude `Foo3.png` and `Foo7.png` from these, test these separately.

```bsh
for name in Foo[0-9].png; do
    case $name in (*[37].png) continue; esac

    # process "$name" here
done
```

Or, using `bash` syntax,

```bsh
for name in Foo[0-9].png; do
    [[ $name == *[37].png ]] && continue

    # process "$name" here
done
```

---

As Stéphane Chazelas mentions in the comments below, you may use an extended globbing pattern in `bash` to test for digits other than `3` and `7`.  Enable extended globbing patterns with `shopt -s extglob`, then use the pattern

```bsh
Foo!(!([0-9])|[37]).png
```

But it would be quicker for me personally to write the script as in the first half of this answer (or use `Foo[01245689].png` for that matter), run it, and be done, before deciding that I believe that this expression is doing the right thing (it does).

Comment: `Foo[^37].png` would work in dash. The only shells I know where it doesn't work are the Bourne shell and ksh88 and bosh (both derived from the Bourne shell). (and fish, but that's because it doesn't support bracket expressions at all)

Comment: Note that in `bash` (and most of the usual locales), `[0-9]` matches hundreds of different characters, not just 012345679

Comment: In `bash -O extglob`, see also `!(!([0-9])|[37])` (which would be more like `vim`'s `[37]\@!\d`)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas `Foo[^37].png` does "work" in `dash` but only if you want the files `Foo3.png`, `Foo7.png` and `Foo^.png`.

Comment: with what version of dash?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas `dash-0.5.11.5`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas The `pdksh` shell also behaves like `dash`, both in and outside of POSIX mode.

Comment: Oh. I see what's going on, `dash` uses `fnmatch()` these days (when compiled with `configure --enable-fnmatch` which Debian / Ubuntu do), so it depends on what your system's `fnmatch()` does there. Debian's (GNU's) `fnmatch()` does understand `[^37]`. What system are you on? Did you compile `dash` by hand? Good point about pdksh though.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I see. Good catch!  I'm on BSD and I can reproduce the same behavior on all BSDs (macOS, NetBSD, FreeBSD, and OpenBSD). It's only really (Ubuntu) Linux that allows using `[^...]` as `[!...]` in `dash`.

Comment: And debian. The `d` in `dash` was initially for Debian. It was a new port of NetBSD sh for Debian. In any case, that has nothing to do with the kernel ("Linux"). More about whether it was compiled with `--enable-fnmatch` or not and if yes, whether `fnmatch()` (from the libc, not the kernel) supports `[^x]` or not.

Comment: Note that `[^37]` works in dash on FreeBSD at least when built with `--enable-fnmatch` like on Debian, and with `/bin/sh` there (which is also based on the Almquist shell). It's true that the `dash` that you can install there with `pkg install dash` doesn't support `[^x]`, presumably because it was not built with `--enable-fnmatch`.

Comment: @they: In the problem that motivated my question `Foo[^37].png` didn't work but `Foo[!37].png` did.  Based on your answer, however, I created a virgin test case in an an initially empty folder.  Both patterns work.  Something else was not right in the original problem (the files for which have since been erased).  Thanks for your answer.